# Role assignment for an outside/foreign group with az cli?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-cli

What I'm trying to do is use a foreign/outside AAD Security Group in a Role Assignment.
I tried with az cli (because the portal does not give me the option to choose Groups from another Directory):

So, I have a resource in Directory # 1 and a Security Group in Directory # 2

`az role assignment create --role <role_name> --assignee-object-id <securityGroup_objectId(from Directory#2)> --assignee-principal-type Group --scope <ressource(from Directory#1)>`

The error that I get is:

> Principal '' does not exist in the directory ''.

I have also tried using `--assignee-principal-type ForeignGroup` instead of `--assignee-principal-type Group`

My problem is that I do not understand how should I specify the AAD when I'm using the ForeignGroup, this is the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/role/assignment?view=azure-cli-latest#az_role_assignment_create) I've found

Comment: This seems to be used for giving access to CSP partners, is that your use case? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/partner-center/reinstate-csp?tabs=workspaces-view

Comment: Nope, just trying to give access to a Security Group from another AAD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like that can be used for assigning access to a CSP partner: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/partner-center/reinstate-csp?tabs=workspaces-view.

I'm pretty sure that you can't just grant a security group from another tenant access in your subscription.